# Smoothbars meets infolines

Tags: beamer, themes, navigation, mini-frames

I like the intuitive navigation that `smoothbars` provides. However, when the presentation has too many sections it is hard to display it nicely. In that case I would like to have a split header like `infolines`.

Thus, how can I have the best of both worlds, have the navigation of `smoothbars` and the split header of `infolines`, like this:

[image]

I have the section in the left, and the navigation on the right. I searched, but without any success.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
%\useoutertheme{infolines}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\section{Test 2}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\frame{two}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\section{Test 3}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\frame{three}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own navigation bar displaying only the mini frames of the current section for use in the `headline` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}

% Smoothbars meets infolines
% (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112571)
\makeatletter
\def\insertminiframescurrentsection{%
  \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}
  \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
    %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
    \ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section\ifnum##2>0\ifnum##3>0%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \hbox to 0pt{%
      \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
      \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
        \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
        \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
        \kern\beamer@tempdim
        \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
        \hbox{\beamer@link(##4){%
            \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
            \ifnum\c@section=##1%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
                \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=##3%
                  \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
                \else%
                  \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
                \fi%
              \else%
                \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
                %\color{fg!50!bg}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              %\color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
    }\fi\fi\fi%
   \ignorespaces
    }
  \vbox{{%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=0\relax%
    \hbox{\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{\kern1sp}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
        \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill%
        \global\beamer@section@min@dim\z@
        \dohead%
        \beamer@section@set@min@width
      \box\beamer@sectionbox\hfil\hskip.3cm}%
  }}}

\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \usebeamerfont*{headline}
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}
    \usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{frametitle}
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(global.bg);%
      color(1ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
      color(5ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}\vskip-5ex% Remove this line if you don't want a shadow below the headline
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertminiframescurrentsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \usebeamerfont{headline}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,vmode]{frametitle}
    \vskip.5ex
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \strut\par%
      \else
        \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi%%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \vskip.5ex  
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.5ex,dp=0ex]{empty}
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@belowframetitle}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{test1}
\begin{frame}{Title}one\end{frame}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\section{Test 2}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\frame{two}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\section{Test 3}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\frame{two}
\frame{three}
\subsection{test1}
\frame{one}
\end{document}
```

[image: headline of the beamer theme "infolines", with the right half used by a mini frame navigation for the current section (cropped)]

The code of the navigation bar named `\insertframescurrentsection` is very similar to the default mini frame navigation (`\insertnavigation` in [`beamerbasenavigation.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty)) , I just removed the display of the section title and added a check to ensure that only the mini frames of the current section are displayed.

This "bare" mini frames line is then used in the beamer template `headline`, which is a copy of the `infolines` headline with the display of the subsection name replaced by the custom navigation bar.

Comment: That works excellent for the navigation. However, when you have a title the gradient in the `smoothbars` does not exist in the navigation part, and you get a step instead. Test with `\begin{frame}{Title}one\end{frame}` you will see.

Comment: @adn I see - themes including shadows can be tricky sometimes... I added a redefinition of the beamer template `frametitle` to my answer which hopefully solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. Is there a way to include the shadows? or I have to live without them?

Comment: @adn You can define your own shadow below the headline, see my edit. I left out the shadow between the headline and the frame title (if present) though, because it looks very weird due to the bi-colored headline.